# How to count specific words in multiple PDFs and it should be presented in a table using R

Tags: r, dataframe, count, keyword, cpu-word

I have multiple PDFs. I want to create a table where the frequency of specific keywords are counted and tabulated. I want the output to look like this;

```
Company name.  Year   ID.   Keyword count
Colgate        2011    1       5  
Colgate        2012    1       0  
Colgate        2013    1       6
Colgate        2014    1       5  
Pfizer         2011    2       3  
Pfizer         2012    2       2  
Pfizer         2013    2       1
```

I applied the following code but it doesn't count the keywords.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LkPQF.png)

Comment: Post your code as text please, not image.

Comment: Don't tell us what the code doesn't do, tell us what it does do, and why that's not what you wanted it to do. Is it printing error messages or computing the wrong thing or returning 99 for things that should be 66 or what?

Comment: At a glance it looks like `P1` is being overwritten inside the loop, so after the loop the `P1` object will have the value from the last item in the loop and none of the others will have any effect.